# Topologies such that every point has a finite number of neighborhouds

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Are there results known about topologies such that every point is just contained in a finite number of open sets (or neighborhoods)?

Comment: An example I can think of is that any topology you define on a finite set will only ever even have a finite number of open sets. Also the topology which consists of only $X$ and $\emptyset$ as open sets has every point only in one open set (namely $X$). Were you looking for something else?

Comment: yes, that are not the only examples, so this conditions seems to be more general. see my comment under drhab's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class that has been studied are spaces such that each point has a smallest neighbourhood, your spaces are among them.

For such a space denote the smallest neighbourhood containing $x$ by $U_x$. Then $x\le y\iff U_x\subset U_y$ defines a poset (provided the space is $T_0$), and since $U_x=\{y\colon y\le x\}$, the order defines the topology.

Some of the results that Svinepels hints at carry over to this more general setting.

These spaces were first considered by Alexandroff[1] (called discrete spaces, „Der Begriff eines diskreten Raumes ist mit dem Begriff einer teilweise geordneten Menge identisch“) and are now called Alexandroff spaces. Results about homotopy types and weak homotopy types of finite spaces (some of it may either be more general or be carried over to more general settings without problems) are in Stong[2] and McCord[3]. I found these references right now by looking at the list of references in Barmak and Minian[4]. You my also find [this webpage by May](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/finite.html) helpful.

[1] P. Alexandroff, Diskrete Räume, Mat. Sb. (N.S.) 2 (1937), 501-518.
http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=5579&option_lang=eng

[2] R.E. Stong
Finite topological spaces
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., 123 (1966), pp. 325–340
http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1966-123-02/S0002-9947-1966-0195042-2/

[3] M.C. McCord
Singular homology groups and homotopy groups of finite topological spaces
Duke Math. J., 33 (1966), pp. 465–474

[4] Jonathan Ariel Barmak, Elias Gabriel Minian, Simple homotopy types and finite spaces, Advances in Mathematics, Volume 218, Issue 1, 1 May 2008, Pages 87-104, ISSN 0001-8708, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2007.11.019.

Comment: thx, do you remember references or names under which those topolgies are known?

Comment: @Stefan, I have added some references. Und ich sehe, dass Du den Alexandroff ja sogar problemlos lesen kannst, wenn Du magst.

Comment: Danke. Genau das mache ich gerade, wobei "problemlos" hier relativ ist, mit algebraischer Topologie und Komplexen kenn ich mich (noch) gar nicht aus.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that every point is contained in a finite number of open sets
and denote $O_{x}$ for the intersection of open sets containing $x$.
Then $O_{x}$ is open and $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ iff $O_{x}\subset N$.
If the topology is $T_{1}$ then $O_{x}=\left\{ x\right\} $
for every $x$ and we are dealing with the discrete topology. This on a finite set (if not then you could find infinite open sets that contain $x$). As Svinepels answers (I was just too late) *every* topology on a finite set will do, simply because in that case the number of open sets is finite. Proved is now that in the non-trivial case (topologies on infinite sets) only topologies that are not $T_{1}$ can meet the conditions.

Comment: good point! yes finite topologies and the trivial topologies are examples which have those properties, and as you pointed out in the infinite case just topologies that are not $T_1$ are interesting. Let me give another example: Let $A = \{a,b\}$ and consider $A^*$ (the sets of finite sequences, i.e. the free monoid) and let $\{ A^*uA^* : u \in A^* \}$ be the basis sets, i.e. those sets of expressions over $A$ which have $u$ as a factor, then each $v \in A^*$ is just contained in a finite number of basis sets, cause it has just a finite number of factors.

Comment: Indeed. If $v$ is contained in such a basis set then $u$ is a subword of $v$ and the number of subwords of $v$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Finite topological spaces would satisfy the property you're asking for. It is known, for instance, that every finite simplicial complex is weakly homotopy equivalent to a finite topological space. This makes it possible to calculate homotopy groups of certain spaces from a finite viewpoint.